# Copy Searched Rows from DataGridView to Another DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, datasource

How we can **copy one or more than one rows from a data grid view to other data grid view** on same form. Here, I've searching option which search from the first grid and if found some matching rows then copy them to 2nd grid. How I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ConvertGridToTable();  // Add data in Datatabledt from gridview
Clipboard.Clear();
DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, Datatabledt);
MessageBox.Show("Data Copied.");
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
```

Now the Datatabledt is available in Clipboard which you can paste in the second gridview which you can do with this:

```
DataObject data = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
DataTable dt = (DataTable)data.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    dtData.ImportRow(dr);
}
dtData.AcceptChanges();
grdProgramData.DataSource = dtData;
MessageBox.Show("Data Pasted.");
```

**EDIT:**

For **one or more rows** you can achieve that with looping through selected rows.

**EDIT**

This is the content in ConvertGridToTable

```
private void ConvertGridToTable()
{

    if (Datatabledt.Rows.Count > 0)
    { }

    Datatabledt = dtData.Clone();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow gr in YOURGRIDVIEW.SelectedRows)
    {
        DataRow dc = Datatabledt.NewRow();
        dc["KEY-FIELD"] = Int32.Parse(gr.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        .....

        Datatabledt.Rows.Add(dc);
    }
    Datatabledt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: ConvertGridToTable (); can you describe this ... is it predefined or user defined and if it is user defined then what is to be done and how ?